# How to make a trigger for sql server 2008 after insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have a table named `Page` and the table has a column named `Priority`. I want that when I insert a row in the page table the priority column take the value of the inserted row `PageId`. `PageId` is my table primary key.

I wrote this trigger for it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PagePriority
ON [Page]
AFTER INSERT
AS
Begin
update inserted
set [Priority]=(select PageId from [Page] where Page.PageId=inserted.PageId)
End
```

But I have some errors on the `set` line.

How to do this?

Comment: You cannot update the "pseudo table" `Inserted` - you need to update **your own table** instead!

Comment: @marc_s Yeah youre right.Got it.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (assumes that PageId is an int)

```
CREATE TRIGGER PagePriority
ON [Page]
AFTER INSERT
AS
Begin

DECLARE @thePageId integer = 0
SET @thePageId = (SELECT PageId from inserted)

update [Page]
set [Page].Priority = @thePageId where [Page].PageId = @thePageId

End
```

Comment: Your code is wrong and won't produce correct results if more than one row will be inserted. SQL Server triggers are **statement** based as opposed to row based. One should always take this into consideration.